# Render again react-native application Web-View

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a react-native app with webview.
I want to go to predefined page (navigate to a page) when I click on a notification, but the application not render the new view.
This is code when I open application (without notification click):

```
return (
  <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://my-url/',
    }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    style={{
      marginTop: 25,
    }}
  />
);
```

And, when I click on notification:

```
return (
  <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://my-url/new',
    }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    style={{
      marginTop: 25,
    }}
  />
);
```

When I click on notification, the application open in https://my-url again.

I want to navigate on https://my-url/new when I click on notification.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use state to set url for webview. When the state changes the webview will reload with the updated url.

Initialize the url state with 'https://my-url/'

Assuming you are using class component, in your constructor set the initial url.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        url: 'https://my-url/'
    }
}
```

When you click on notification, set the state with the desired url.

```
onNotification: function(notification) {
    this.setState({
        url: 'https://my-url/new'
    })
}
```

This should render predefined page in webview

```
return (
  <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{
      uri: this.state.url,
    }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    style={{
      marginTop: 25,
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: I have the same issue in a react hooks implementation where I manage the source of the WebView with a state. But I too see a new window (bottom sheet upon my mobile app in iOS 16) which is unexpected.